# Send select value axios react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, react-typescript

I'm trying to send an select value from a registration form.
I'm using ReactJS with TypeScript.
For now I dont know how can I send this value :
[image: image1]

This is my register component :

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import "./login.css";
import AuthService from "../services/auth.services";

type Field = {
  value?: any;
  error?: string;
  isValid?: boolean;
};

type Props = {};

type State = {
  civility: any;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  message: string;
  successful: boolean;
};

export default class Register extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleRegister = this.handleRegister.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      civility: "",
      first_name: "",
      message: "",
      successful: false,
    };
  }

  validationSchema() {
    return Yup.object().shape({
      civility: Yup.string().required("Champ obligatoire !"),
      first_name: Yup.string().required("Champ obligatoire !"),
    });
  }

  handleRegister(formValue: {
    civility: any;
    first_name: string;
  }) {
    const {
      civility,
      first_name,
      last_name,
    } = formValue;

    this.setState({
      message: "",
      successful: false,
    });

    AuthService.register(
      civility,
      first_name,
    ).then(
      (response) => {
        this.setState({
          message: response.data.message,
          successful: true,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        const resMessage =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();

        this.setState({
          message: resMessage,
          successful: true,
        });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { successful, message } = this.state;

    const initialValues = {
      civility: "",
      first_name: "",
      message: "",
    };
return (
<Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={this.validationSchema}
          onSubmit={this.handleRegister}
         >
          <Form>
            {!successful && (
              <div className="login">
                <div className="box-registration">
                  <div className="log-box-title">Register</div>
                  <Field as="select" name="civility" className="nuage">
                    <option disabled={true} value="choose">
                      Choose an option
                    </option>
                    <option value="MR">Mr</option>
                    <option value="MME">Mme</option>
                    <option value="DR">Dr</option>
                  </Field>
                  <Field
                    name="first_name"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    className="input-login"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <button type="submit" className="login-button">
                    <span>Register</span>
                  </button>
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            {message && (
              <div className="form-group">
                <div
                  className={
                    successful ? "alert alert-success" : "alert alert-danger"
                  }
                  role="alert"
                >
                  {message}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </Form>
        </Formik>
```

This is my service :

```js
import axios from "axios";

const REG_URL = "https://localhost:3001/wp-json/app/v2";

class AuthService {
register(civility: [], first_name: string) {
    return axios
      .post(REG_URL, {
        civility,
        first_name
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.token) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }

        return response.data;
      });
  }
```

When I click on button, nothing is appening. But if I delete select section it work normaly !

Thanks you for your helping, If you need anything, please say me and please excuse me for my english.

PS : I'm using Axios for send my request.

Comment: Please also add your code from `AuthService.register`.

Comment: @sandrooco its okey i have edited my post

Comment: Are you sure that handleRegister is trigerred? Try adding a console.log.

Comment: @sandrooco yes because when i delete my <select> and <option> its work